# Error Handling - Controller's OnException and Application_Error

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to MVC. Below is the code that I have added to an existing MVC 5 application.  The code is using log4net to log any run-time error/exception.

**NOTE:** I could override `OnException()` in MVC filter "HandleErrorAttribute" but I preferred to have this functionality in my custom `Controller` base class.

Can anyone please review and provide feedback?

**BaseController.cs**

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    private log4net.ILog logger;

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //Log error
        logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filterContext.Controller.ToString());
        logger.Error(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception);

        //If the request is AJAX return JSON else redirect user to Error view.
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            //Return JSON
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    Data = new { error = true, message = "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            //Redirect user to error page
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    ...
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Log exception
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        log.Error(exception);

        //Clear error from response stream
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();

        //Redirect user
        Context.Server.TransferRequest("~/Error/");
    }
    ...
}
```

For displaying errors, I have a basic ErrorController.cs with just `Index()` Action along with its associated Error/Index.cshtml.

Some blogs suggests different error pages for different type of errors (such as 404 error). Do I need to handle them separately?

Please share if you have any ideas to improve upon my code in terms of usability and logging details.

Answer (score 12):

The `OnException()` methods does 2 things.

1. It logs the exception
2. It creates an return value

So let us refactor these two points to two separate methods.

```
private void LogException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
{
    logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(exceptionContext.Controller.ToString());
    logger.Error(exceptionContext.Exception.Message, exceptionContext.Exception);
}
```

---

```
private const String XMLHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";
private const String XRequestedWithHeadername= "X-Requested-With";
private const String JSONErrorMessage = "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.";
private void CreateExceptionContextResult(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
{
    if (exceptionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[XRequestedWithHeadername] == XMLHttpRequest )
    {
        //Return JSON
        exceptionContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new { error = true, message = JSONErrorMessage }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //Redirect user to error page
        exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        exceptionContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
}
```

If we want to handle the different error types, we should create a new class which only keeps the values for actionName and controllerName.

```
public class ActionControllerName
{
     public String ActionName { get; private set; }
     public String ControllerName { get; private set; }
     public ActionControllerName(String actionName, String controllerName)
     {
         ActionName = actionName;
         ControllerName = controllerName;
     }
}
```

Now we add a Dictionary and a method to fill this dictionary, which should be called in the constructor, or injected by an property.

```
private const int DefaultEntryKey = -1;
private Dictionary<int,ActionControllerName> redirectDictionary = new Dictionary<int,ActionControllerName>();
private void FillRedirectDictionary()
{
    redirectDictionary.Add(DefaultEntryKey , new ActionControllerName("Index", "Error"));
    // more to add
}
```

Next we implement a method to get a `RedirectToRouteResult` passing the exception as parameter

```
private RedirectToRouteResult GetRedirect(Exception exception)
{
    int errorCode = DefaultEntryKey;
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null) 
    {
        errorCode = httpException.ErrorCode;
        if (!redirectDictionary.ContainsKey(errorCode))
        {
            errorCode = DefaultEntryKey;
        }
    }
    ActionControllerName acn = redirectDictionary[errorCode];
    return this.RedirectToAction(acn.ActionName , acn.ControllerName);
}
```

We go back to this `else` part

> ```
> else
> {
>     //Redirect user to error page
>     exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
>     exceptionContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
> }
> ```

and change it to

```
else
{
    //Redirect user to error page
    exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    exceptionContext.Result = GetRedirect(exceptionContext.Exception);
}
```

Comment: @heslacher this creates a major problem that I'm having to deal with now: it just binds the original url to the error redirect url forever even after you get rid of the exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143304/trapping-an-exception-using-iexceptionfilter-and-redirecting-permanently-binds-t